# need to create a function builiding function

Tags: ocaml

I need to fill in an implementation for the function build that generates random expressions. The function is of type build : (int*int -> int)*int -> expr . The function is called with the argument pair (rand,depth) .

The first element rand is a random number generator of type int * int -> int . Each call rand (i,j) returns a random integer between i inclusive and j exclusive. Use this function to randomly select operators when composing subexpressions to build up larger expressions.

The second element depth is a maximum nesting depth. A random expression of depth d built by randomly composing sub-expressions of depth d-1 , and the only expressions of depth 0 are VarX or VarY .

The function uses this data type i created

```
type expr =
      VarX
    | VarY
    | Sine of expr
    | Cosine of expr
    | Average of expr * expr
    | Times of expr * expr
    | Thresh of expr * expr * expr * expr
```

and calls these :

```
let buildX()                       = VarX
let buildY()                       = VarY
let buildSine(e)                   = Sine(e)
let buildCosine(e)                 = Cosine(e)
let buildAverage(e1,e2)            = Average(e1,e2)
let buildTimes(e1,e2)              = Times(e1,e2)
let buildThresh(e1,e2,e3,e4)       = Thresh (e1,e2,e3,e4)
```

to build each part of it
this is what the function starts like:

```
let rec build (rand,depth)
```

Im assuming I match a random number with the builds so like 1- sine 2-cosine 3-average 4-times (not using thresh) like this

```
let rec build (rand,depth) = match (rand(1,4),depth) with
```

and basically need to create a random expression with a certain depth.  It says I need to create random expressions of depth -1 and use depth = 0 for var x and var y but i dont really understand this concept and also am not sure if i always need to make a var x and a var y or just need one of them.
Any help on how to approach this would be appreciated.

I created this function :

```
let rec build (rand,depth) = match (rand(1,8),depth) with 
|(_,0) -> if(rand(1,3) = 1) then buildX() else buildY()
|(1,_)-> buildX()
|(2,_)-> buildY()
|(3,_)-> buildSine(build(rand,(depth-1)))
|(4,_)-> buildCosine(build(rand,(depth-1)))
|(5,_)-> buildAverage(build(rand,(depth-1)),build(rand,(depth-1)))
|(6,_)-> buildTimes(build(rand,(depth-1)),build(rand,(depth-1)))
|(7,_)-> buildThresh(build(rand,(depth-1)),build(rand,(depth-1)),build(rand,(depth-1)),build(rand,(depth-1)))
|(_,_) -> buildX()
;;
```

What I want it to do is first check if depth is zero and if it is then randomly pick 1 or 2 and buildX or buildY depending on which it picks.
If depth is not zero I want to match with the result of random (could be from 1 to 7) and depending on which one I get I call the appropriate expression builder. `(_,_) -> buildX()` should never be executed and is just the default case if nothing else gets matched. I think Im not using random correctly though because my matches give me a syntax error.  And idea on what Im doing wrong?

Comment: As you observed in a previous question, an expression is a tree whose leaves are `VarX` and `VarY`. It follows that a depth-0 tree must be either `VarX` or `VarY`. It can't be both, that doesn't really make sense. Other than that I can only say that you can call `rand (1, N)` to make a random choice among N things. At the leaves you have 2 things. Inside the tree you have 5 things.

Comment: I created this function :

Comment: you seem to be using rand correctly in this context. Can you load rand into the toplevel and execute some random number generation?

Comment: rand should be implemented like,  `let rand (a,b) = assert(a<=b); (Random.int (b-a)) + a`

Comment: I should point out how you are calling functions with `()` (`unit`) is inappropriate. A function of that type should have a side effect, you are just constructing things, you should do that directly. Generally, you don't use the `()` in the c/java-style arguments, but separate them by spaces `let buildSine e = Sine e`. The `(args...)` is the syntax for constructing tuples.